# mp4 not playing in Firefox 35 on Mac, wrong MIME type?

Tags: macos, firefox, ffmpeg, html5-video, mp4

I got two mp4-Videos, both with the same codes (h264 for video and aac for audio), which are returning different mime types on linux:

```
$ file --mime-type one.mp4
one.mp4: video/mp4

$ file --mime-type two.mp4
two.mp4: video/qicktime
```

*two.mp4* wont play in Firefox 35 on a certain Windows installation and a Mac OS X 10.10 installation, while *one.mp4* does.

I compared the videos with ffmpeg, and the Video-Stream lines are:

one.mp4:

> Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x640 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 735 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)

```
Metadata:
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

two.mp4:

> Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 1024x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1002 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 600 tbn, 50 tbc (default)

```
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-01-23 14:16:08
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
  encoder         : MainConcept H.264
```

Can this be a reason for the difference in MIME-Type?
And what could I do to change that?

Merci beaucoup.

Comment: I just tried to change the _handler_name_ metadata, which resulted in deletion of all metadata except for _handler_name=VideoHandler_  – and suddenly ```file --mime-type``` returns _video/mp4_!

Comment: The heck! Deleting the Metadata solved the problem, the video is playing in Firefox now!